# Постепенное движение фигуры в ту точку холста, где пользователь кликает левой кнопкой мыши

Tags: python, ооп, анимация, pyside2, qpropertyanimation

Необходимо запрограммировать постепенное движение фигуры в точку холста, где пользователь кликает левой кнопкой мыши.

Координаты события хранятся в его атрибутах **`x`** и **`y`** (`event.x` , `event.y`).

**main.py**:

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication
from PySide2.QtCore import QPropertyAnimation, QPoint


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(500, 500)
        self.child = QWidget(self)
        self.child.setStyleSheet("background-color:green;border-radius:25%;")
        self.child.resize(50, 50)
        self.anim = QPropertyAnimation(self.child, b"pos")
        self.anim.setDuration(1500)
        self.anim.start()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.anim.setEndValue(QPoint(event.x(), event.y()))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Проблема в том, что событие выполняется всего единожды, при первом нажатии в указанную точку. 
Если затем попробовать кликнуть в другое место холста, то фигура не будет двигаться.

Как можно решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
'''
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication
from PySide2.QtCore import QPropertyAnimation, QPoint
'''
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(500, 500)
        
        self.child = QWidget(self)
        self.child.setStyleSheet("background-color: green; border-radius: 25%;")
        self.child.resize(50, 50)
        
        self.anim = QPropertyAnimation(self.child, b"pos")
        self.anim.setDuration(1500)
        
#---        self.anim.start()


# ???  def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):                                   # +++
# ------------------------------------------> vvv <-------> vvv <------------    
        self.anim.setEndValue(QPoint(event.x()-25, event.y()-25))      
        self.anim.start()                                               # +++


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @zur9h пожалуйста.  Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour